# Switch menu with pure css?

Tags: javascript, css

**Update**
I used radio buttons, so you can only open one Item. But you cant close it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5YNF/)

I'm wondering if its possible to make my menu in pure CSS. Now I modify the css with javascript.

Note: I'm not using Jquery or any other lib, thats not my question.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5uQ/) of the menu I want to make in pure css

HTML:

```
<div class="menuItem" onclick="mySwitch(0)">Click Item 1</div>
<div class="subItem">Hi there</div>

<div class="menuItem" onclick="mySwitch(1)">Click Item 2</div>
<div class="subItem">Some text over here.</div>

<div class="menuItem" onclick="mySwitch(2)">Click Item 3</div>
<div class="subItem">Tnx for clicking</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .menuItem {
        display:block;
        width:100%; 
        height:20px;
        background:#ff0;
    }

    .subItem {
        display: none;     -- Hide the submenu
    }
```

Javascript

```
function mySwitch(nr) {
    var itemsArr = document.getElementsByClassName('subItem');    
    for(var i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; i++) {
         var item = itemsArr[i];
         if(i == nr) {
             if(item.style.display == 'none') {
                 item.style.display = 'block';
             } 
             else {          
               item.style.display = 'none';
             }
         } else {
             item.style.display = 'none';
         }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You can hack this by using a radio button style configuration to open/close the submenus, if that is what you are after. See this for example: [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/). You can modify that to fit your needs.

Comment: Try Googling "pure css accordion"

Comment: Or check [CSSPlay Menus](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/) for all your menu needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to prevent the excessive use of JavaScript when you can reach the same result with CSS but sometimes it is necessary to change DOM elements and apply some "tricks" to get it to work and that is not so good at all.

Look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UWYcv/2/)** with only CSS3. You can do a similar effect but with hover event instead of a click event. You can change `:hover` to `:active` but that will only work if you keep pressing mouse button inside the DIV elements.

This `.menuItem:hover + .subItem` CSS rule is showing the next `.subItem` element of hovered `.menuItem`

Since you do not want to use JavaScript events, you can't apply a class to the element. If you did so it would be easier. This way, **using only CSS**, you can apply some tricks like using checkboxes instead of DIV elements and use their `:checked` property as CSS rules to show the sublinks.

Something like this:

```
<label for="m1" class="menuItem">Click Item 1</label>
<input id="m1" class="cb" type="checkbox">
<div class="subItem">Hi there</div>

<label for="m2" class="menuItem">Click Item 2</label>
<input id="m2" class="cb" type="checkbox">
<div class="subItem">Some text over here.</div>

<label for="m3" class="menuItem">Click Item 3</label>
<input id="m3" class="cb" type="checkbox">
<div class="subItem">Tnx for clicking</div>

.cb {
    display: none;
}

.cb:checked + .subItem {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6gT/)**

Comment: Tnx this is what i was looking for. So its not possible only using divs. Styling the inputs with css will work.

Comment: @JohanHoeksma glad it helped. It would be possible using only divs if there was a `:clicked` state. But unfortunately there is not.

Comment: Only problem is that the other tabs are not closing when i click another one.

Comment: That's because each checkbox is independent. Selecting one of them does not modify the others. You can use radio buttons instead but after select one, you cannot deselect all. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cdVuA/

Comment: People running into this solution should note that you can avoid the whole `for="whatever"` mess with labels if you wrap `input` in `label`. For example: `<label><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label>`. Note I used `span` because `div` would violate specification. You can however force `span` to be block element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could take a look to this tutorial: [Link](http://designmodo.com/css3-accordion-menu/)

hope this helps